# MonoDevelop - how do I look at stderr from a compile?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm using MonoDevelop and MonoTouch to build a project, but whenever there is a compile error in gcc, it simply says (in the Build Output tab), "Process exited with code 1, command: ..."

The problem is, I can't see what error gcc gave. It looks like stderr is either ignored or stuffed into a logfile somewhere.

I thought I might be able to discover the gcc/stderr output if I copy that command to a terminal window and run it, but it won't compile because some of the files on the command line were temp files that MonoTouch setup, and they were removed after MonoDevelop tried to build.

I've tried:

1. Setting Log Verbosity to Diagnostic
   under
   MonoDevelop->Preferences->Build
2. Running mdtool on the command line
   with -v and that doesn't show me any
   gcc output either
3. Adding
   --stderr=/Users/myname/somefile.txt to the mtouch command line under
   Project Options->iPhone Build->Extra
   Arguments

.. none of those things work.

So.. how can I get the stderr output from gcc when mtouch runs it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add "-v -v -v" to the "Extra Arguments" for your build configuration in the iPhone Build settings.

Answer (score 0):

In the build results window, mouse over the right end of or click on the step causing the error. A small icon will show up at the end of the line. It looks like an oval with horizontal lines going through it. If you click on that, you will see the commands that were run in that build step, as well as the output of those commands.